# Spring security XML: how to express?

Tags: spring-security

I have an application using Spring security to control the access to its endpoints.
There are two endpoints **/aaa** and **/bbb** secured as:

```
<security:http pattern="/aaa/**">
    <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/aaa/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/aaa/**" access="#oauth2.hasScope('aaa_scope')" />
</security:http>

<security:http pattern="/bbb/**">
    <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/bbb/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/bbb/**" access="#oauth2.hasScope('bbb_scope')" />
</security:http>
```

I need to move **/bbb** under **/aaa**, i.e. to make it into **/aaa/bbb** while maintaining the original security checks

- for the "bbb" part (now relocated)
- and for the "aaa" part *except* for the "bbb" part parked under it.

How do I express this in Spring security XML?

What would a descriptor incantation look like?

====================

I tried the following naive combination

```
<security:http pattern="/aaa/bbb/**">
    <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/aaa/bbb/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/aaa/bbb/**" access="#oauth2.hasScope('bbb_scope')" />
</security:http>

<security:http pattern="/aaa/**">
    <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/aaa/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/aaa/**" access="#oauth2.hasScope('aaa_scope')" />
</security:http>
```

but empirically observed that it allows the holder of aaa_scope (not having bbb_scope) to access **/aaa/bbb**.

Apparently failing an access via first descriptor causes the request not to be aborted right there, but going on try the remaining descriptors.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: What is your problem? Just move it.

Comment: If I simply change /bbb to /aaa/bbb, then (as empirically observed) "bbb" becomes accessible to the holder of aaa_scope, not having bbb_scope, even if I move the descriptor for /aaa/bbb to the top, ahead of the descriptor for /aaa.

Comment: If you move it into the first one (before you edited the question) should work. However, I think your problem is that you have two lines in every chain. It makes no sense, if you don't change the pattern. Only the first one will be matched. So every authenticated user can access `/aaa/bbb/**`

Comment: Empirical experience using Spring 4.x shows that authenticated user having ccc_scope, but not having aaa_scope or bbb_scope, cannot access /aaa or /bbb.